# Why the RPT file of Crystal Report Viewer is not getting displayed properly through autoIt script

Tags: crystal-reports, reportviewer, autoit

I am using crystal report viewer to display reports through AutoIt script. But the RPT file is shrinking in size thereby cutting the view. I could get only half of the report view. The problem is intermittent as sometime the report would generate perfectly fine and the same piece of code and setup is working absolutely normal for other PCs(except mine) in windows machine.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far. Where is the code?

Comment: I am taking the RPT file from the local, and trying to display it through AutoIT script. I am attaching the part of displaying code:

Local $CRHeight=1024-50
Local $CRWidth=768-50 
$CRViewer1 = ObjCreate("CRViewer.CRViewer"
$CRViewer1.ReportSource = $CrystalReport $hndReportViewer = GUICreate ( "Crystal Reports - " & $sReportTitle, $CRHeight, $CRWidth,(@DesktopWidth-$CRHeight-50)/2, (@DesktopHeight-$CRWidth-50)/2,BitOR($WS_SIZEBOX, $WS_MINIMIZEBOX, $WS_MAXIMIZEBOX))
If $hndReportViewer = 0 Then
MsgBox(0, "Error", "Could not create Window to display Crystal Reports control")
Exit

Comment: I guess the issue is related to PC configuration, as it is working absolutely fine in others system.